# Question about the value of Output voltage ripple mentioned in power modules datasheets

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb-design, analog

I am searching for a power module that takes +15V and converts it to -15V but one important spec is the "Output Voltage Ripple" rating. I found this module from TI: [PTN78000A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ptn78000a.pdf)

I found that its output voltage ripple is 2% Vout(pp) which is equivalent to 300mVpp in my case and this is not acceptable for me. I understand that the output ripple depends on the filter (caps and ferrite bead for example) at the output of the power module, so does this mean that the 2% written in the datasheet is for the module alone without any output filters?

Also, If I want to reduce this 300mVpp to say 50mVpp, how can I design the output filter so that it can cause this reduction in ripples?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities as expressed in the datasheet.

1) The ripple is highly dependent on output operating current. So if you are not truly
sourcing a very high output current (>= say 3A), your ripple will go down dramatically for
low power applications (e.g. 20mvpp for ~150mA, p5. fig 2.)

2) Additional input output ceramic capacitors of 1-4.7uF are expected to reduce (high freq) ripple between 10-30%. (Fig 19.).

If I had the part, I would experiment more in lab, as that number seems more like a max on the datasheet (they only show one value, rather than min/max range), when looking over some of the common operating characteristics.

Also, if ripple was a major concern, I'd probably try to first look around non switching based regulators.

Comment: Non-switching regulators for polarity reversal, not sure that is feasible.